# My python code works on playground, but doesn't work in python

Tags: python, input

I would like to ask you to help me.

I just started to learn python and got a problem.
I have 2 codes:

```
que = input("Europe floor?\n")
usf = int(que) + 1
print("US floor", usf)
```

and:

```
nam=input('Who are you?\n')
print('Welcome,',nam)
```

I just copied them from the lesson's video.

My problem:

These two codes work perfectly in the playground (py4e). Python asks me, gives me an opportunity to write the answer, remembers it, and then prints the result.

BUT! When I type these codes into Python, I can see next...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUtQL.png)

and

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDgIW.png)

I pushed just `Ctrl+V` and `Enter`. I can't write answers after questions.

When I save these codes as files `*.py`, I can see the question, then I type any, push Enter and window closes.

What I do wrong? Where is the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: You're trying to run this code with Python 2.x, in which case you need to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` (or better yet, upgrade to a Python version that isn't obsolete).

Comment: I use Python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

I think you just pasted the whole thing, and the interpreter misses some of the lines. Try entering it line by line

Answer (score 0):

[image: Check this]

> 'usf' is not defined basically means that the variable 'usf' which you are trying to use is not defined

Comment: I cannot assign a value to a variable 'usf'.